# Tinymce Yii2 не отображается иконка в тулбаре

Tags: yii2, tinymce

Подключаю Tinymce в Yii2

```
echo $form->field($model, $row['name'])->widget(TinyMce::className(), [
                                'options' => ['rows' => 20],
                                'language' => 'ru',
                                'clientOptions' => [
                                    'plugins' => [
                                        "advlist autolink lists link charmap print preview anchor",
                                        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                                        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
                                    ],
                                    'toolbar' => "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | responsivefilemanager link image media",
                                    'external_filemanager_path' => '/admin/plugins/responsivefilemanager/',
                                    'filemanager_title' => 'Responsive Filemanager',
                                    'external_plugins' => [
                                        //Иконка/кнопка загрузки файла в диалоге вставки изображения.
                                        'filemanager' => '/admin/plugins/responsivefilemanager/plugin.min.js',
                                        //Иконка/кнопка загрузки файла в панеле иснструментов.
                                        'responsivefilemanager' => '/admin/plugins/responsivefilemanager/tinymce/plugins/responsivefilemanager/plugin.min.js',
                                    ],
                                ]
                            ]);
```

И хотя я прописал ***image*** в тулбаре, в редакторе иконка не показывается. В консоле есть только одна ошибка

```
GET http://dubno.w4u.com.ua/admin/news/edit/skin-config.html 404 (Not Found)
```

Может из-за ее не работать? Или в чем может быть вообще проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В плагины тоже нужно добавить `image`, и если у вас есть такой плагин, то заработает.

Если нет, то выдаст в консоль ошибку о том что плагина нет. Суть в том, что бесплатная версия TinyMCE не даёт возможности загружать изображения, поэтому есть много разных решений для того, чтобы это прикрутить, вот парочка из них:

1. Используйте для TinyMCE вот это расширение: https://github.com/PendalF89/yii2-filemanager
   Внизу есть пример подключение для TinyMCE. Мне этот вариант понравился, поэтому использую его.
2. Или попробуйте это решение: http://nex-otaku-ru.blogspot.ru/2016/07/tinymce-responsive-filemanager-yii2.html

**UPD** При ближайшем рассмотрение видно, что автор использует второй вариант, а значит возможно нужно привести `plugins` к такому виду и проблема решится:

```
'plugins' => [
            "advlist autolink lists link charmap hr preview pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount textcolor visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen nonbreaking",
            "save insertdatetime media table contextmenu template paste image responsivefilemanager filemanager",
        ],
```